# Estrutura de branchs e merge .NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, git, versionamento

Tenho a seguinte estrutura de branchs para projetos ASP NET MVC

- Master - versão de produção
- DEV - Desenvovimento
- Release - Manutenção de bugs

Essa estrutura já estava definida quando cheguei no projeto e estou com um problema quando na hora da homologação e publicação em produção.

O fluxo é o seguinte:

- Novos desenvolvimentos são feitos no branch de dev. Merge de master para dev.
- Ao terminar a tarefa é feito o commit (usamos o GIT) em dev e faço o publish no servidor de aplicação de homologação. No caso de aprovação merge de dev com master.

Neste ponto tenho 2 problemas.

- Se 2 dev's estiverem desenvolvendo no projeto MVC ao gerar o publish para homologação um dev pode sobrescrever o publish do outro atrapalhando a homologação.
- Se a homologação do Dev1 for aprovada e a do Dev2 não como eu vou publicar uma versão em produção sem levar as alteraçõs do Dev2 já que ele fez o commit da sua task.

O mesmo pode ocorrer para manutenções. Branch de release porque para iniciar a correção de um bug é feito o merge de master com release, commit em release e merge de release com master.

Alguém já passou por uma situação parecida? Como eu posso garantir desenvolvimento paralelo garantindo o correto versionamento e evitando enviar versões não homologadas para produção?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- O correto seria publicar apenas do master, e não de um branch de desenvolvimento. Além disso, cada correção de bug ou desenvolvimento deve ter o seu branch em separado, e não usar um único branch para todos os esforços de desenvolvimento.
- Correções de bugs devem começar com um branch inicado em **master**;
- Um branch **não deve ser publicado em produção**. *Master* deve receber o branch e a publicação deve ser feita por **master**. *Branches* de homologação devem ser publicados apenas em instâncias de desenvolvimento;
- Novas funcionalidades começam com um **branch** em **master** (por exemplo, um *Sprint* em *Scrum* merece um branch só pra ele). Todo novo item de desenvolvimento (por exemplo, um ítem de um *backlog Scrum*) também deve ter seu **branch** em separado;
- Cada ítem de backlog deve entrar como *merge* em cima do *branch* pai, e este *branch* pai, quando o desenvolvimento termina, deve ser reintegrado ao **master**
- *Merges* de *master* em *branches* de desenvolvimento **devem ser evitados**. *Merges* bidirecionais não funcionam muito bem em qualquer controle de versão que seja.

[Neste extenso manual de boas práticas há esses argumentos que usei melhor desenvolvidos](https://sethrobertson.github.io/GitBestPractices/).

Comment: No caso do item 3. Master recebe meu branch (item de backlog por exemplo). Após a publicação o usuário não homologou, porém, outras pessoas colocaram também enviaram suas alterações para master e precisam publicar em prod. Como vou fazer para não enviar as alterações não homologadas já que elas estão em master também?

Comment: Isto aqui não pode: "O usuário não homologou e outras pessoas enviaram para master". É claramente uma falha processual. Se o usuário precisa homologar, você deve publicar o branch que recebeu todos os outros branches-filho de funcionalidades, e não tentar colocar ainda as correções de bugs tudo no mesmo branch, senão vira bagunça. Editei a resposta pra isso ficar mais claro.